# Javascript: How to split string into n-byte chunks?

Tags: javascript

I have a large string and I want to split it into an array of 500 byte strings. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: 1 character = 1 byte, so length of 500 should work

Comment: o didn't know that. thanks!

Comment: i.e. string.slice(0, 501)

Comment: What environment are you working in?

Comment: Node. i'm using react

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Nope. Usual JS string encoding uses 2 bytes per character. (UCS 16)

Comment: @Edmund Have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html then for dealing with bytes

Comment: hm didn't know that thanks